# CloudKit and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, cloudkit

I have a very simple app that consists of a ListObject, each ListObject can have ItemObjects.

I wanted to use CloudKit as my backend. I have the following code.

```
override public init() {

    super.init()

    cloudContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "ListModel")

    cloudContainer.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unresolved error \(error)")
            return
        }

        self.viewContext = self.cloudContainer.viewContext
        self.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        self.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy


        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print("Unable to Perform Fetch Request")
            print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}


lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<ListObject> = {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ListObject> = ListObject.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated",
                                                     ascending: false)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                              managedObjectContext: self.viewContext,
                                                              sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                              cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()

var lists:[ListObject] {

    get {
        guard let list = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else {
            return [ListObject]()
        }

        return list
    }

    set {}
}
```

I listen for updates to the FetchedController and update the table view accordingly:

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    print("Update received")
    self.delegate?.reloadTable()
}
```

However the controllerDidChangeContent function seems to be called randomly, and only sometimes (e.g. on loading the app). Is there another notification I should be listening for when the CloudKit db is modified (e.g. on the macOS client)

Comment: The delegate methods are called whenever the context was saved (having changes). You should implement the corresponding `controllerWillChangeContent`method and also `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)`. In `willChange` call `beginUpdates`, in `didChange` call `andUpdates` and in `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` call the methods to insert, delete. move and update the table view rather than calling `reloadData` once.

Comment: The problem is that if I save the data on my macOS client,  the 'controllerDidChangeContent' method is not called on my iOS client (or at least is called inconsistently)

Comment: The problem might be the computed property, you are likely deactivating your previous controller every time you access it because you are recreating it every time. Also, just use the controller directly you don't need `lists`